# Outlook olMailItem.Attachments.Add - does an attachment have to be on the filesystem?

Tags: email, vba, ms-word, outlook, ms-office

Is there a way to add an attachment to an email you're sending out without the attachment being on the filesystem? From reading over the DOM  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175153%28office.12%29.aspx) it says that the attachment source can be either a file path or "an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment". I don't use VBA of the office DOMs all that much and I'm not sure what this is. In addition, all the examples I can find are only giving usage examples by using the filesystem path.

I'm calling this from Word for documents that create themselves by filling out some form fields, then print themselves. I'd like them to go out via E-mail as well, but have no need for a permanent copy of the created file. I do realize that I could save them off to a temp directory, attach the saved file, then delete the file once the mail object is sent. It seems a waste to do this though.

Is there an way I can have Word pass the in-memory Document object off to Outlook to attach to the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot attach an in-memory document to an outlook mailitem without saving it to disk first.

Answer (score 0):

Oesor,

I made an assumption that email should get sent automatically, so SendMail method is out.
 I tried a couple of things to see whether it would work. In both cases code would be embedded in your Word file.
 In pre-2007 Word you could use RoutingSlip functionality:

```
 ActiveDocument.HasRoutingSlip = True   'Creates RoutingSlip
 With ActiveDocument.RoutingSlip
   .Subject = "email Subject"
   .AddRecipient = "recipient@domain.com"
   .Delivery = wdAllAtOnce
 End With
 ActiveDocument.Route
```

Apparently, this code doesn't work in Word 2007. So instead you can use SendForReview functionality:

```
ActiveDocument.SendForReview "recipient@domain.com", "email subject", False, True
```

Email gets sent right away (w/o the popup Outlook window), but a couple of caveats exist: the document has to have a corresponding file - it won't work for a new document that has never been saved, and the first time the recipient opens the attached document from e-mail there may be a popup message about starting the review process.

I hope this helps,

Max.

Comment: Actually, I really don't care about the popup that .MailSend generates. However, your caveat has exactly what I'm looking to not do -- generate a file by filling in some fields, then need to save it to disk before attaching it as a document.

I also need to specify the contents of the mail and simply attach the document, so I guess I'll live by saving it to temp, attaching it, then deleting it when done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, if the relevant attachment source is an inline item, such as an embedded image.  I have not tried it with attached files that are not inline but it *may* work there too.  The basic ideas are:

1) Treat the content of the Emails as a Word document because the native Editor for Outlook is Word.

2) Use Word's Copy and Paste to carry everything around with you via the Clipboard because it is a well tested approach.  In the example, I have pasted the new section in at the start in a new Paragraph but you could obviously place it anywhere you want.

The strange thing is, though, (see the `Debug.Print`) that the Attachments Count in the To document does not change, even though the inline images are all where they should be and can be seen and Sent.  Have Outlook fun!  (The `.olm` files in the example are simply Outlook.MailItems that have been saved as Template files.  They could just as easily be MailItems from an Outlook folder.)

```
Private Sub TestAttach()
'Places inline Attachment information into a different MailItem
Dim OlTo As Outlook.MailItem
Dim OlFrom As Outlook.MailItem
Dim DocTo As Word.Document
Dim DocFrom As Word.Document
Dim R As Word.Range
Dim R1 As Word.Range
Dim R2 As Word.Range
Dim lStart As Long
Dim lEnd As Long

Set OlFrom = Outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Temp\OlTemplateWithSomeOtherAttachments.oft")
Set OlTo = Outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Temp\OlTemplateWithSomeAttachments.oft")
Debug.Print "From file starts with " & OlFrom.Attachments.Count & " attachments."
Debug.Print "To   file starts with " & OlTo.Attachments.Count & " attachments."
Set DocFrom = OlFrom.GetInspector.WordEditor
Set DocTo = OlTo.GetInspector.WordEditor
OlFrom.Display
OlTo.Display

Set R2 = DocFrom.Content
With R2.Find                    'Note: Find settings are 'sticky' and do not need to be repeated on the next find.
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop          'Do not loop back to the start of the document
    .Format = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Text = "Start flag for Section with Attachments"  'Find the start of the section to move
    .Execute
    lStart = R2.Start
    .Text = "End flag for Section with Attachments"    'Find the end of the section to move
    R2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Execute
    lEnd = R2.Start
End With
'OlFrom.Display
Set R2 = DocFrom.Range(lStart, lEnd)
'R2.Select
R2.Copy
Set R = DocTo.Range(1, 1)
R.InsertParagraphBefore
'Place the new inline attachments in the To MailItem
Set R = DocTo.Range(1, 1)
R.Paste
OlTo.Display
Debug.Print OlTo.Attachments.Count; "To   file ends with " & OlTo.Attachments.Count & " attachments, the same as the original number but all the inline images show."
End Sub
```